# HTML newsletter - Gmail spacing above and below hyperlinked images

Tags: html, newsletter, spacing

I'm trying to create a HTML document which is to be sent out as a newsletter, but unfortunately it's not showing correctly in Gmail.

For some reason I am getting spacing issues above and below images which are hyperlinked. Like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P0yrv.png

I have tried adding:

style="border-spacing:0;"

to my table as seen elsewhere, as well as the below to all images:

style="display:block;"

Any ideas?

Edit: here's the html as it stands:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<head>
<title>LCTSA</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
<table id="Table_01" width="701" height="375" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing:0;">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" rowspan="2">
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183839.png" width="473" height="279" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
  <td>
   <a href="mailto:example@co.uk" style="display:block;"><img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183840.png" width="227" height="145" alt="" 

style="display:block;"></td></a>
  <td>
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183848.gif" width="1" height="145" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183841.png" width="227" height="179" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183848.gif" width="1" height="134" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="4">
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183842.png" width="29" height="96" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
  <td>
   <a href="mailto:example@co.uk" style="display:block;"><img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183843.png" width="176" height="14" alt="" 

style="display:block;"></td></a>
  <td rowspan="4">
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183844.png" width="268" height="96" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183848.gif" width="1" height="14" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="3">
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183845.png" width="176" height="82" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183848.gif" width="1" height="31" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <a href="http://www.google.co.uk" target="_blank" style="display:block;"><img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183846.png" width="227" height="24" alt="" 

style="display:block;"></td></a>
  <td>
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183848.gif" width="1" height="24" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183847.png" width="227" height="27" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
  <td>
   <img src="http://www.morley.leeds.sch.uk/user/74/183848.gif" width="1" height="27" alt="" style="display:block;"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As @SLaks indicated. Also GMail may be post-processing your HTML, so you might want the check that side as well.

Comment: How do I check whether Gmail is post-processing my HTML @Buddy? Seemed nothing I've tried so far has worked >_<

Comment: There should be a `show original` option. I find Gmail mucks up a lot of my HTML, sometimes directly changing the HTML itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `<a>` `display: block`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment SLaks. I've just tried doing that though for the 3 links and it hasn't changed it :(

a href="mailto:example@example.com" style="display:block;">

Comment: Hrmmm. Seems even after I remove all a tags, the images still don't align properly.